# React: Filename appended to url

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, axios

Any idea why `index.css` would start showing up as the `:id` in axios requests?

In order to deploy to Heroku, I set up a proxy in React `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"`. However, since setting up the proxy in both prod and dev environments I've been getting a really strange issue with the `:id` field in calls on page refresh (only page refresh).

For whatever reason, `index.css` is being appended so a normal page refresh request for `axios.get(/document/:id)` throws this error: `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /document/index.css from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/` and this is what hits the backend: `GET /document/index.css` In this example, `:id` was supposed to be params.id.

This is happening to all routes defined in `<Router>` as `/path/:id` regardless of whether I hard code in an :id value or use a dynamic one.

This issue does not occur when I test with an earlier version where the proxy is not set up and `localhost:3000` is hard coded into all axios routes.

I'm happy to provide further explanation/examples. Really scratching my head here, any idea what's going on? Thank you very much!

Edit: Requested Public index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dropdown-options"></div>
    <div id="root"></div>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share your public `index.html` file

Comment: @92yo Just added it as an edit. It's worth mentioning that the app has 2 css files and the index.css file is created by tailwind.

Comment: I believe your problem lies with how you're importing your css file. 

so try linking it as such ommiting the `.` - `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/index.css'` 

let me know if that solved your problem

Comment: @92yo Removing the dot fixed it.... Thank so much for your help! If you post your answer i'd be happy to mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem lies with how you're importing your css file.

so try linking it as such ommiting the `.` - `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/index.css'`

let me know if that solved your problem